# How to disable the OK button of a modal dialog in jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to disable the OK button of a modal dialog after pressing OK button in jQuery.

Comment: are you saying in the dialog one ok is hit you want the same button to be disabled ?

Answer (score 2):

Write the disable action in your Ok button click event as following

```
"Ok": {                          
       click: function () {
          $(".ui-dialog-buttonpane button:contains('Ok')")
                          .attr("disabled", true)
                          .addClass("ui-state-disabled");
                        }
      }
```

Above code will get all the buttons in your dialog and select the Ok button and adding attribute disable only to that button.

Comment: +1 for the jquery class change. I couldn't use this because my app is localized, but your answer pointed me in the right direction. I added a localized answer in another example and used e.target instead of a jquery path to select the button. cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
"Ok": {
    click: function (e) {
        $(e.target)
            .attr("disabled","disabled")
            .addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        return false;
    }
}
```

or if its localized:

```
buttons = {};
buttons[strings.buttons.ok] = function(e){
    $(e.target)
        .attr("disabled","disabled")
        .addClass("ui-state-disabled");
    return false;
}
```